# How to call a method of an observable in angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to call a business method after subscribe to an observable with rxjs but I cannot make it work. What I'm missing?

```
observable$.subscribe(value: A => {
  value.businessMethod();
});
```

```
class A {

  public businessMethod(): number {
    ...
  }
}
```

> ERROR TypeError: "value.businessMethod is not a function"

Comment: what kind of observable is it?

Comment: Are you getting any data in 'value'?

Comment: How are you initializing the observable? How are you pushing a value into the observable after initializing? Observables may be hot/cold depending on how they are initialized. Could you show more code?

Comment: please add a line where you define observable$ in your code

Comment: How does the complete class A look like? and what is `observable$` specifically. Please proviode a [mcve]

Comment: The type of observable$ is Observable<A>, returned by HttpClient. I can access any field but no function, in both the component controller and in the template. Sorry if I'm not so explanatory, but I'm new to Angular and that's my first question on StackOverflow.

Comment: ... so please show the service code where you populate the data to `observable$`. I, personally,  have an idea of what the issue is, but I cannot know for sure if you are not showing all relelvant code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error occurs when `obervable$` does not hold a value yet. Its value is undefined. Please try

```
observable$.pipe(
  filter(Boolean),
).subscribe(value: A => {
  value.businessMethod();
});
```